# Does Lennox not allow users to buy parts directly?

Tags: heat-pump

I have a heat pump XP15-030-230-04 which is not defrosting. Opening the panel did I find DS1 and DS1 leds fast flashing alternatively which as per their manual is a fault with the Coil Sensor. I thought a replacement coil sensor was all I needed until I figured Lennox works throgh dealers and the ones I called don't sell parts directly. So my question is: 1. Does Lennox not sell parts directly to customers 2. Is there any way I could get the part I need (Coil Sensor)
[image: Page 13 of XP15 Heat Pump Manual]
[XP15 Manual](https://www.completeheating.ca/images/pdf/LennoxXP15.pdf)

Comment: Might depend on your location.  It is difficult to get some parts for a furnace in Ontario.  If the part also fits another device there is a work around.

Comment: In the USA there is a thing going around called "Right to Repair" which on the surface allows customers to buy parts to repair there items. There are a lot of problems with it at this point. Maybe somebody is doing that in your country. The idea is to let the user solve this type of problem.

Comment: 1) Almost certainly not. 2) You hand the guy on the other side of the counter the thing and say, this is for a Lenox XP15-030-230-04.... *gimme*. - I guess I'm pretty spoiled living in Chicago; I'm probably less than half an hour from at least 20 **parts stores**. And they've never not had the thing or were unable to get it. They don't sell to you; they sell to them, and that's where you're supposed to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the alternative name for coil sensor is `Defrost Thermostat`

Under that name it is available on the market.

I found this place that claims to have it (for a hefty price), so you might find other places.

[defrost](https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Defrost-Thermostat/95M54/2346913)

Comment: Thank you for your lead - it might be either the one you linked (more probable) or this one https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Temperature-Sensor/28W71/2710326. I'll have to open the existing one to see which one matches. But thank you, I'm not bumping on a wall anymore it looks!

Comment: once you have the right model, you can find cheaper places to get it

Comment: Of course. Done!

Answer (score 2):

I am not at all surprised that Lennox, or many other appliance, HVAC, etc. manufacturers, will not supply directly to end users.

- Returns/complaints are likely to be much higher with ordinary users than with authorized dealers or factory-trained technicians
- There is a significant internal business cost per order. Easy to justify exceptions to send a single part on an emergency rush order to a regular dealer (who ordinarily buys thousands of dollars of stuff at a time). Not so easy with one-time customers. We're all spoiled by Amazon, Walmart, etc. but the reality is that *unless* you set up a very high-efficiency and high-volume distribution network the internal order cost will be quite high.
- For *some* parts, there are regulatory and/or liability issues - especially anything dealing with refrigerant. Which are not a problem with an authorized dealer or technician as the manufacturer will already have the paperwork on file to satisfy these concerns.

The good news for *many* things is that you can find alternative sources. Many times that includes the internet. I have purchased many appliance parts (washer, dryer, oven, etc.) from online retailers that specialize in appliance parts. I also generally find that local appliance, electrical and HVAC parts/supply houses (you won't find them in your local mall, but they are in every city) will sell *most* things to the general public, provided:

- You walk in knowing what you want - not necessarily the exact part, but at least model numbers and types of parts.
- You don't expect consumer-level support (Q: how do I install this? A: call a technician)
- You *may* pay up to double what the technicians pay. This varies a lot - some of them will give you trade pricing easily, some won't. If it is a $5 part it just doesn't matter, but if it is a $150 part it makes a real difference.

The smart places will know that a sensor or control board is *not* a refrigerant issue and not ask you to show that you area certified for refrigerant recovery/etc.

The stupid places won't sell you anything that goes inside an air conditioner or heat pump unless you are certified.

And there are places that just won't care and will sell anything to anyone, particularly if you are paying cash.

Answer (score 0):

Lennox responded to my email saying "..Lennox does not sell to consumers, only to Certified HVAC Technicians. ref:_00D80LcQA._5003c1gnCwO:ref"